# Microsoft Access - Group By Feature

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the results of one of my queries.  Right now, I have a query in which the output shows the number of items in certain type of category by date, by using the Group By feature. So just as an example, if I enter 9/15/13 as the date the output would be  as follows:

Apples 1
Bannas 5
Pears 16

Is there a way for it to just show Apples and total all other items into one category so it would output:

Apples 1
All Others 21

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: What are your table definintions?

Answer (score 1):

A bit difficult without table names or column names, but something along the lines of this (you'll have to enter it in SQL view)

```
Select
    IIf([Product] = 'Apples', 'Apples', 'All Others'),
    Count(*)
From
    [Inventory]
Where
    [InventoryDate] = [Enter Date]
Group By
    IIf([Product] = 'Apples', 'Apples', 'All Others')
```

You need to replace Inventory with your table name, and Product with the column that contains the category and InventoryDate with the column that has the date. `Count(*)` might be `sum([Quantity])`, it depends on your structure.